# Glassfish - read a file - a correct directory

Tags: java, path, glassfish, directory

I'm writing a web application using Jersey and Glassfish. I need to load a file. In my project it's in a direcory src/main/resources/example.txt. Everything's working in Tomcat, but when I run it in Glassfish I'm getting FileNotFoundException. It's not finding a file, because when I try to get a path in Glassfish, it's showing me a Glassfish directory: \glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain\config\src\main\resources\example.txt instead of a directory of a project when I got my files. How can I change it? Or is there a way to configure a project to copy files to a demanded directory while compiling?

Comment: are you deploying as a war file in both servers?

Comment: In pom.xml file I got it configured as <packaging>war</packaging>

Answer (score 1):

I am new to glassfish. But i think it should work.

```
final String instanceRoot = System.getProperty( "com.sun.aas.instanceRoot" );

if (instanceRoot == null)
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException( "Cannot find Glassfish instanceRoot. Is the com.sun.aas.instanceRoot system property set?" );
}

File configurationFolder = new File( instanceRoot + File.separator + glassfishDomainConfigurationFolderName );
File configFile = new File( configurationFolder, fileName );
```

Comment: Well, what you wrote gives me a Glassfish directory, but what I wanted to achieve is to get to a file in a directory of a project I'm building (like MyProjectsName/src/main/resource/example.txt) and I don't know how to get there using Glassfish

Comment: then you should use
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/package/name/file.txt");     File file = new File(url.getFile());

Comment: url variable is returned as null here. And if it you meant something like this:
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".");
System.out.println(url.getPath());
then the path here I'm getting is something like:
C:/Users/me/workspace/glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain/lib/classes/
and sadly glassfish folder is not what I would like to get.